# WaitForMultipleObjects when bwaitall is false

Tags: c++, windows

Having a hard time understanding this part of the docs.

> If bWaitAll is FALSE, the return value minus WAIT_OBJECT_0 indicates the lpHandles array index of the object that satisfied the wait. If more than one object became signaled during the call, this is the array index of the signaled object with the smallest index value of all the signaled objects.

Let's say I have 2 handles. If the return value of WaitForMultipleObjects  is 1, how do I know which handle got signaled ?

I assume that it is the first handle that got signaled because it has index 0, the index 1 indicates that the second handle (index 1) is still in a wait state.

Comment: You said it yourself. 'The return value minus WAIT_OBJECT_0 indicates the lpHandles array index of the object that satisfied the wait'.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says, if the wait is satisfied by a signaled element in the array, the return value will be in the range of `WAIT_OBJECT_0 to (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + nCount-1)`, so simply subtract `WAIT_OBJECT_0` from the return value to get the array index, eg:

```
DWORD dwResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(...);
if ((dwResult >= WAIT_OBJECT_0) && (dwResult < (WAIT_OBJECT_0+2)))
{
    DWORD index = dwResult - WAIT_OBJECT_0;
    ...
}
```

`WAIT_OBJECT_0` has a value of 0, so if the array has 2 elements and the return value is 1, it means the *2nd* element is signaled.

Comment: Let's say return value is 1
1- WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 1-0 = 1
Then the index 1 would indicate the index of the object that satisified the wait meaning that object 1 is still waiting ?   according to the sentence: "If bWaitAll is FALSE, the return value minus WAIT_OBJECT_0 indicates the lpHandles array index of the object that satisfied the wait. " so if return value is 1 , it means that handle 1 satisfied the wait and is still in in a wait state.

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed, so index 0 is the 1st array element, index 1 is the 2nd array element, and so on. And no, the array element that satisfied the wait is no longer waiting, it has been signaled, that is the whole point of the `WaitFor...()` functions, to detect when things are signaled.